# One-word term for «Done with errors»

Tags: single-word-requests

Could you please suggest any one-word term that is synonymous to «Partially successful» or «Done with errors» or «Done with exceptions» (all these expressions are not exactly the same, but in our circumstances they are more or less equivalent)?

Comment: Please give an example sentence that demonstrates how the word would be used.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Well, this is not exactly a sentence. Okay, the situation is as follows. Large chunk of data is being uploaded to our server. The server may return «Done» (which means full success), «Error» (if data were so corrupted that server gave up) or «the term I am asking about» (most of the data were uploaded but some failed). The problem is that the uploading status form designed in such a way that expressions like «Done with errors» does not fit the corresponding cell width, that we can't alter, so it becomes truncated: «Done with e...» and this looks ridiculous.

Comment: The example sentence is required by the [*Single-word-request*](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) tag.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of such a tag.

Comment: I believe what you are describing is what most programming languages delineate as **errors** and **warnings**, where an error is something that will truly mess up execution, possibly corrupt data, and a warning is not good, but everything should still work. Perhaps in your database you could just say, "warnings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incomplete** seems like the most natural choice, but I would say **imperfect** gets closer to the meaning of "partially successful" than "partially complete".

Answer (score 1):

**"Inaccurately," "erroneously,"** or **"erringly"** could be used here.

Inaccurately:

> in a way that is not correct or exact [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inaccurately)]

Erroneously:

> in a mistaken way; incorrectly [[Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/erroneously)]

Erringly:

> in an erring [err: make a mistake] way [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/erringly)]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think any of these terms fits. All of them create impression there has been failure (due to inaccuracy or an error). Please check my comment to the original post (I, probably, should have described the situation in the original post, sorry for that).

Comment: @S.N. Ok.  I didn't see that comment.  For the future, add context before you post the question the first time so you don't get answers like this.  No worries, though!